# Returning absolute difference between time periods

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to calculate the absolute difference in values between different time periods per sales agent.

So from this dataset:

```
Report month    ID Vendedor   sum     count   Rental Charge
 2018-07-01       803621.0   780.81     42       4
 2018-07-01       900000.0   100.90     20       5
 2018-08-01       803621.0   1132.71    77       3
 2018-08-01       900000.0   1000.10    10       2
```

I would want to get this outcome:

```
Report month    ID Vendedor   sum     count   Rental Charge     Diff
 2018-07-01       803621.0   780.81     42         4             0  
 2018-08-01       803621.0   1132.71    77         3           351.90
 2018-07-01       900000.0   100.90     20         5             0
 2018-08-01       900000.0   1000.10    10         2           899.20
```

This is what I have tried:

```
two['pct_change'] = one.groupby(['Report month','ID Vendedor'])['sum'].pct_change()
```

and this is the outcome I got:

```
Report month    ID Vendedor   sum     count   Rental Charge     Pct_change
 2018-07-01       803621.0   780.81     42         4               NaN  
 2018-08-01       803621.0   1132.71    77         3               NaN
 2018-07-01       900000.0   100.90     20         5               NaN
 2018-08-01       900000.0   1000.10    10         2               NaN
```

I know pct_change returns the percentage change but I was going to convert this percentage into an absolute number

Comment: How is counts `351.90` ?

Comment: @jezrael sorry, mistake on my part, it should be the difference between sum for each ID Vendedor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
#if necessary
#one = one.sort_values('Report month')
one['diff'] = one.groupby('ID Vendedor')['sum'].diff().fillna(0)
one = one.sort_values('ID Vendedor')
print (one)
  Report month  ID Vendedor      sum  count  Rental Charge   diff
0   2018-07-01     803621.0   780.81     42              4    0.0
2   2018-08-01     803621.0  1132.71     77              3  351.9
1   2018-07-01     900000.0   100.90     20              5    0.0
3   2018-08-01     900000.0  1000.10     10              2  899.2
```

Comment: Thanks. What I meant was the difference from one month to another  for each ID Vendedor

Answer (score 6):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) 
to sort the DataFrame, 
then we can use [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [`GroupBy.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) to create the `Diff` column:

```
new_df = (df.sort_values(['ID Vendedor','Report month'])
            .assign(Diff = lambda x: x.groupby('ID Vendedor')['sum']
                                       .diff().fillna(0))
         )
print(new_df)
  Report month  ID Vendedor      sum  count  Rental Charge   Diff
0   2018-07-01     803621.0   780.81     42              4    0.0
2   2018-08-01     803621.0  1132.71     77              3  351.9
1   2018-07-01     900000.0   100.90     20              5    0.0
3   2018-08-01     900000.0  1000.10     10              2  899.2
```

---

We could also use [`GroupBy.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) and [`Series.sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html)

```
(df.sort_values(['ID Vendedor','Report month'])
   .assign(Diff = lambda x: x['sum'].sub(x.groupby('ID Vendedor')['sum']
                                          .shift())
                                    .fillna(0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `diff` after sorting the dataframe:

```
# Sort
df = df.sort_values(by=['ID Vendedor', 'Report month'])

# Compute diff
df['Diff'] = df['sum'].diff()

# Set to 0 when vendor changes
mask = df['ID Vendedor'] != df['ID Vendedor'].shift(1)
df.loc[mask, 'Diff'] = 0

# Sort again?
df = df.sort_values(by='Report month')
```